# Про утечку памяти с time.AfterFunc

Tags: golang, таймер, утечка-памяти

Хотелось уточнить: будет ли течь память при такой реализации *TTL in-memory*-кеша:

```golang
package cache

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Cache struct {
    *sync.Map
    TTL time.Duration
}

func New(ttl time.Duration) *Cache {
    return &Cache{
        Map: new(sync.Map),
        TTL: ttl,
    }
}

func (c *Cache) Store(key, value interface{}) {
    c.Map.Store(key, value)
    // memory leak?
    time.AfterFunc(c.TTL, func() {
        c.Map.Delete(key)
    })
}
```

**P.S.** Предполагаемый размер кеша — несколько десятков тысяч объектов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Утечки быть не должно, так как в
[документации](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer)
к типу `time.Timer` и его методам нет ничего про обязательные
деструкторы как у `time.Ticker`.  При этом в вашем коде как
минимум две проблемы:

1. Вы создаёте множество таймеров, что увеличивает потребление ОЗУ
   и создаёт дополнительную нагрузку на планировщик.
2. Если вы положите значение по ключу дважды, сотрётся оно по истечении
   первого *TTL*, а не второго.

И то, и другое можно вылечить, если просто запоминать время установки
значения и проходиться по всем значением раз в *N* миллисекунд,
удаляя устаревшие.